# In due time and place

Tags: expressions

Caveat: the content of this post might be a little bit politics-related. But I try to make it sound as non-political as possible. Let's focus on the linguistical problems here, thanks!

> If I were to create a sports league, I would make sure that every player in my league had the opportunity to protest **in due time and place**.

This is a sentence I wrote. The following Google ngram shows that it is a rather old-fashioned expression. Mostly it is seen in older contexts.

[image] I wonder is it okay to use it in my writing?
[ngram: in due time and place](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20due%20time%20and%20place&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20due%20time%20and%20place%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cin%20due%20time%20and%20place%3B%2Cc0)

I also wonder whether it can be rewritten as follows:

> If I were to create a sports league, I would **give** every player in my league **due time and place** to protest.

Answer (score -1):

When normally using the expression, "and place" isn't used. Well, not in first person with the I - he said he would allow all the players in the league due time on the field.